COPY INTO snowflake XML limitations
So I understand that there is a 16MB limit when loading XML files into variant column within Snowflake.
Data looks like
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">
    <output>
        <response>
            <person>
                <id>123</id>
                <name>John</name>
            </person> 
            <person>
                <id>124</id>
                <name>Ava</name>
            </person> 
        </response>
    </output>

I am only interested in the person data and flattening the attributes into a table.
I am trying to load XML file that is larger than 16MB. is it possible to strip further outer elements, or another workaround within Snowflake itself?
Or is the only option to split the file before loading into Snowflake with another tool?

I am not 100% sure about this but have you tried loading that to a stage? Maybe you can parse out what you need from the stage file before loading into the table?

we have an external stage as the data is in S3


Or is the only option to split the file before loading into Snowflake with another tool?

An alternative is to put "raw" XML file into Snowflake stage using preferred method:

PUT
Snowsight UI
ETL Tool

Then process staged XML file with Snowflake function or stored procedure(Python, Java, Scala) to a desired form and save results into a table.
More at:

Reading files
Processing unstructured data with UDF and procedure handlers

